# API csv import unable to import addresses

Tags: api, import

I am importing a large dataset using the API csv import extension.

I have imported the custom fields, contacts, email and phone numbers using the different entities.

I have tried to import the address fields (street address, supp 1, supp 2, city, country) and have failed. I am using location ID = 1 and matching on civicrm contact id.

Nothing is happening to the contacts at all according to the contact log but the importer thinks the job is done. No new contacts are created either.

I have tried adding a column address primary = yes but that hasn't made any difference.

Am I missing some required fields or perhas there is some other explanation?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks
Caroline